# Recent issues - when installing Aide on Ubuntu 16.04 - AIDE --init return code 17

Tags: 16.04

does anybody run into similar problem? I use Aide a lot, but recently I have an issue initialising it and it returns

```
Running aide --init...
274:syntax error:"
274:Error while reading configuration:"
Configuration error
AIDE --init return code 17
```

Snippet of lines in `/var/lib/aide/aide.conf.autogenerated`

```
272 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_multiversedeb_binary-@@{ARCH}_Packages(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
273 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_(InRelease|Release(\.gpg)?)$ VarFile
274 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_multiversedeb_i18n_Translation-@@{TRANSLATIONS}(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
275 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_"http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu"_binary-@@{ARCH}_Packages(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
276 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_(InRelease|Release(\.gpg)?)$ VarFile
277 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_"http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu"_i18n_Translation-@@{TRANSLATIONS}(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
278 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_xenial_binary-@@{ARCH}_Packages(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
279 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_(InRelease|Release(\.gpg)?)$ VarFile
280 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_xenial_i18n_Translation-@@{TRANSLATIONS}(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
281 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_main_binary-@@{ARCH}_Packages(\.IndexDiff)?$ VarFile
282 /@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}@@{ROOTPREFIX}var/lib/apt/lists/repo\.mongodb\.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mongodb-org_3.4_(InRelease|Release(\.gpg)?)$ VarFile
```

This is the case even if fresh installation is done.

Versions:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Aide 0.16a2-19-g16ed855
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you need.

EDIT 2018-12-14: I asked same question [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aide/+question/676797).

Comment: Got it sorted. It was sort of stupid issue with my APT configuration (additional PPA repository had double quotes).

Comment: What do you mean ? I have the same issue btw

Comment: I am outside at the moment, but in my case it was incorrectly added APT source list, PPA repository for Oracle Java...

Comment: I delete previous comment as it didn't give much and I couldn't edit it. In my case it was incorrectly added APT source list, PPA repository for Oracle Java. in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` I had a URL in double qoutes which Aide didn't liked. I hope this help

Comment: thank you for responding, I do not have the same issue with sources list so I am not sure, what is wrong, however, I figured out that if I remove the packages  and configs and re-install with defaults my problem does not remain and I can create a DB file and use it as is.